# Whatsapp Bot Reduce Post Request

Tags: bots, webhooks, whatsapp, ngrok, whatsapi

I have a WhatsApp bot app, and I'm using ngrok for webhook services. I've noticed that for every message I receive from the client, WhatsApp sends four POST requests to my ngrok: message, read, delivery, and sent. How can I manage the POST requests and extract only the message to reduce the number of requests?

I tried to mange it from meta developer page but I dont understand how can I control the post request..